# winserver 2008R2-Standard,VC++2015:Unspecified error: 0x80240017

Tags: windows, c++

My os: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 64-bit (6.1,Build 7600)
I tried to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2015(x64 and x86) and i receive this Unspecified error: 0x80240017
before installing vc++2015 i update the system i restart and i try to reinstall vc++2015 and
i got the same error again 
Then i tried  to run Tool.exe and i receive: the program can't start becouse MSVCP140.dll i think this means i have to install vc++2015
I don't know what to do,i tried all tutorials from youtube :P no results

P.S.
I want make it work with 2008 no updates to windows 7,8,10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error `0x80240017` means `WU_E_NOT_APPLICABLE`:

```
//
// MessageId: WU_E_NOT_APPLICABLE
//
// MessageText:
//
// Operation was not performed because there are no applicable updates.
//
#define WU_E_NOT_APPLICABLE              _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x80240017L)
```

This means the update misses the requirements to be installed. Build 7600 means you run the RTM without the Sp1. New updates/software require the installed Sp1.

Solution: Download and install the [Sp1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=5842) to update to Build 7601.

Comment: ok, click on the green button to accept the answer if it helped you: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235